# Using summarise, across, and quantile functions together

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I am trying to use `mtcars` dataset to calculate summary statistics. Here is my code -

```
df <- as_tibble(mtcars)


df.sum2 <- df %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.numeric)) %>% 
  summarise(across(
    .cols = everything(), 
    .fns = list(
                Min = min, 
                Q25 = quantile (., 0.25), 
                Median = median, 
                Q75 = quantile (., 0.75), 
                Max = max,
                Mean = mean, 
                StdDev = sd,
                N = n()
                ), na.rm = T,
   .names = "{col}_{fn}"
                   )
            )
```

But I got the following error -

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
> x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Locations 65, 66, 69, 71, 76, etc. don't exist.
> i There are only 6 columns.
> i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.

If I take out the `Q25 = quantile (.,0.25)` and `Q75 = quantile (.,0.75)` from the above code, it works fine. Actually, I can get the expected results using the following codes -

```
df.sum <- df %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% # select variables to summarise
  summarise_each(funs(Min = min, 
                      Q25 = quantile (., 0.25), 
                      Median = median, 
                      Q75 = quantile (., 0.75), 
                      Max = max,
                      Mean = mean, 
                      StdDev = sd,
                      N = n()))
```

But I want to use the `across` function with the `summarise` function. I do not want to use the `summarise_each` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function or formula syntax while passing additional arguments. Try

```
library(dplyr)

df.sum2 <- df %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.numeric)) %>% 
  summarise(across(
    .cols = everything(), 
    .fns = list(
      Min = min, 
      Q25 = ~quantile(., 0.25), 
      Median = median, 
      Q75 = ~quantile(., 0.75), 
      Max = max,
      Mean = mean, 
      StdDev = sd,
      N = ~n()
    ),
    .names = "{col}_{fn}"
  )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Can you shed some knowledge on how can I know I need to use formula?

Comment: You need to use formula (`~`) whenever you are passing additional arguments to the function. `min` has no additional arguments so you can use it as it is. `quantile` has an additional argument that you are passing which is `0.25` so here you need to use the formula.